# Starting New Rows With Arduino TFT

Tags: arduino, arduino-due, gfx

I am experimenting with writing on a 1.8" TFT Display. I am trying to have the MCU write on each line and have it start a new row after reaching the specified "bottom" of the screen, but it writes to the next row instead of the next line, similar to below.

```
BlahBlahBlahBlah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
```

Whereas I am looking for

```
BlahBlahBlahBlah
BlahBlahBlahBlah
BlahBlahBlahBlah
BlahBlahBlahBlah
BlahBlahBlahBlah
```

From what I can tell, the if-statement is not resetting, so the program writes and sets the cursor back to the top in the next row.

```
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

int lineNumber = 1;
int rowNumber = 1;

void setup(void) 
{

  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);

  while (rowNumber <= 5)
  {
    if (lineNumber > 15)
    {
      tft.setCursor(25*rowNumber, 0);
      rowNumber++;
      lineNumber = 1;
    }

    tft.println("Blah");
    lineNumber++;


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Rather than using the println() function, I used the print() function and explicitly set the cursor to where I wanted it. Shown below.

```
 for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber <= 4; rowNumber++)
   {
 tft.setCursor(25*rowNumber,0);

for (int lineNumber = 0; lineNumber <= 15; lineNumber++)
     {
  tft.setCursor(25*rowNumber, 7*lineNumber);
  tft.print("blah");

  Serial.println(lineNumber);
     }
   }
```